# React can I create 'setState' function in custom hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I successfully applied local storage in my component and would like to create my first hook, which will take care of the local storage, so I can re-use it in my other components.

```
/*   EXAMPLE   */
//useState:
const [state,setState] = useState("");
setValue("Hello"); // WORKS!

//useLocalHook:
const [hook_value,setHookValue] = useLocalStorage("");
setHookValue("New Value"); // NOT WORKING
```

I read guides about custom hooks, but they are not using the setFunction for their custom hooks, is this impossible to do?

**Parent:**

```
   // Local storage
    const [data,setData] = useLocalStorage("mydata","");
    useEffect(()=>{
        setData(new_value);
    },[data]);
```

**Hook:**

```
const useLocalStorage = (storage_key,initial_value) => {

    const [value,setValue] = useState(getLocalStorage(storage_key,initial_value));

    /*          LOCAL STORAGE           */
    function saveLocalStorage(key,value){
        if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
            // Set New Default Value
            const saved_value = JSON.stringify(value);
            console.log(`Key:${key} stored:${value}`);
            localStorage.setItem(key,saved_value);
        }
    }
    function getLocalStorage(key,initial_value)
    {
        if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
            const value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
            console.log(`Key:${key} received:${value}`);
            if(value)
            {
                return value;
            }
        }
        // Not found, return initial value
        return initial_value;
    }
    function clearLocalStorage()
    {
        localStorage.clear();
    }
    function setValue(new_val)
    {
        value = new_val;
    }
    // Save settings in local storage
    useEffect(()=>{
        saveLocalStorage(storage_key,value);
    },[value]);

    // Return value
    return [value];
}
```

What am I not understanding /& doing wrong if it's possible to change the value with custom hooks?

Comment: You're destructuring 2 variables from your hook call `const [data, setData] = useLocalStorage("mydata","")`, but in your hook `useLocalStorage`, it's only returning an array with one element `return [value]`, which should be `return [value, setValue]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `setValue`fn in your custom hook, so you can use used it inside `useEffect`

**Hook**:

```
    const useLocalStorage = (storageKey,initialValue) => {
       const [value,setValue] = useState(getLocalStorage(storageKey,initialValue));

    return [value, setValue]
```

And now in the parent you can use `setData`

**Parent**

```
   const [data,setData] = useLocalStorage("mydata","");
     useEffect(()=>{
        setData(new_value);
     },[data]);
```